# Is there a way to use .htaccess to cache images from a different domain

Tags: image, .htaccess, caching, mod-expires

I use a user's browser cache to cache images that are hosted on my server using a .htaccess file and mod.expires.

Here is what I use:

`ExpiresByType image/gif A604800`

How can I use something similar to cache images from a different domain that I don't have ownership of?

I'm trying to minimize the re-downloading of images a user has already viewed.

Comment: No you can't. The only ways is for your server to download the image, kind of proxy the requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't. To the best of my knowledge, the browser doesn't have any mechanism for fiddling with caching settings.